# How to use process.env. code while debugging with npm dev under WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webstorm, dotenv

I have the following code in `api.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'

const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
    withCredentials: false, 
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})

export default apiClient
```

Unfortunately, at runtime it doesn't know `process.env.` and consequently doesn't work.

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you explain further what's the problem?